# MMDrawerController with Login View as first view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mmdrawercontroller

I am using **MMDrawerController** Library. 
My application is in Objective C. It has a login screen as its first screen. 
**Code for AppDelegate.m**

```
LoginViewController* loginView= [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController"] bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];
    self.loginViewController = navigationController;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now When LOGIN is successful I goto HomeViewController. Here I have to change the rootViewController to MMDrawerController for the Library to work. For this I am writing the following code in ViewDidLoad() of HomeViewController.m

```
-(Void)methodCalledInViewDidLoad
{
  UIViewController * leftSideDrawerViewController = [[MMExampleLeftSideDrawerViewController alloc] init];  
    UIViewController * centerViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController * rightSideDrawerViewController = [[RightViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerViewController];
    [navigationController setRestorationIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]                         initWithCenterViewController:navigationController                        leftDrawerViewController:leftSideDrawerViewController
                             rightDrawerViewController:nil];
    [self.drawerController setRestorationIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    [self.drawerController setMaximumLeftDrawerWidth:200.0];
    [self.drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
    [self.drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];
    [self.drawerController
     setDrawerVisualStateBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible) {
         MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock block;
         block = [[MMExampleDrawerVisualStateManager sharedManager]
                  drawerVisualStateBlockForDrawerSide:drawerSide];
         if(block){
             block(drawerController, drawerSide, percentVisible);
         }
     }];
appDelegate.self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  [appDelegate.self.window setRootViewController:self.drawerController];

}
```

This is not working and showing errors. I have followed all tutorials available. **The rootViewController is not changing to drawerController** in HomeViewController

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDelegate *appDel=(AppDelegate)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  [appDel.window setRootViewController:self.drawerController];
```

Still not working go to MFSlidebar. https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Comment: then goto MSSlidebar.